# Reverse in terms of fold-right and fold-left

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 2.39**
>
> Complete the following definitions of reverse
>   (exercise 2.18) in terms of fold-right
>   and fold-left from exercise 2.38:
>
> ```
> (define (reverse sequence)
>   (fold-right (lambda (x y) <??>) nil sequence))
> (define (reverse sequence)
>   (fold-left (lambda (x y) <??>) nil sequence))
> ```

I wrote this answer:

```
(define (fold-right op initial seq)
  (define (rec rest)
    (if (null? rest) 
        initial
        (op (car rest)
            (rec (cdr rest)))))
  (rec seq))

(define (fold-left op initial seq)
  (define (iter result rest)
    (if (null? rest)
        result
        (iter (op result (car rest)) (cdr rest))))
  (iter initial seq))

(define (reverse sequence)
  (fold-right (lambda (x y) 
                (append  y (list x))) null sequence))

(define (reverse-l sequence)
  (fold-left (lambda (x y) (cons y x)) null sequence))

(define a (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `reverse` using `fold-left` is correct.

In the case of `reverse` using `fold-right`, you may use `snoc` (described below) in place of `append`.  It looks better and its complexity is no worse than that of `append`, so there is no loss in efficiency:

```
(define (snoc e lis)
  (if (null? lis)
      (cons e lis)
      (cons (car lis) (snoc e (cdr lis)))))

(define (reverse sequence)
  (fold-right (lambda (x y)
                (snoc x y)) null sequence))
```

... or even more succinct:

```
(define (reverse sequence)
  (fold-right snoc null sequence))
```

It is curious that SICP's definition of `fold-left` swaps arguments to `op` (but retains the correct ordering of arguments to `op` in `fold-right`), resulting in the use of a rather tedious `(lambda (x y) (cons y x))` instead of a simple `cons`.  [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) gets the definitions of `fold` and `fold-right` correct, of course.

Comment: Thanks!  I was surprised that you didn't have to snoc in reverse order for fold-right, but I tested it and it works.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, youve got it.  I don't think there are any reasonable alternatives.

It's umderstandable if you were hoping to avoid `append` with some clever combo of `cons`/`car`/`cdr` but i dont believe there is such a way.